# What is the best way to fetch records batch-wise from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

**Scenario**: we are fetching rows from SQL Server to C#.Net console application and doing action on the retrieved data from SQL Server through stored procedure; after the action is performed the new data is stored into the MongoDB using C#-MongoDB-Driver.

**Issue**: There are billions of rows. My stored procedure contains query as follows:

```
select * from table_name
```

To work out some batch-wise logic there is no identity column nor any date columns or such.

**Information**: As of now the application is fetching the records upto 3500 - 5000 records and storing into MongoDB and then it throws an error which is as follows:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has  thrown an exception.

**Question**: Can anyone suggest me some logic to work out for batch-wise read/fetch from SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can't use `OFFSET-FETCH` in SQL Server 2012 and assuming the table has a primary key or column(s) that allow you to uniquely identify a row, lets call it `UniqueKey`, then in 2005 upwards you could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx) like this...

```sql
SELECT UniqueKey, col2, col3 
FROM 
(
  SELECT UniqueKey, col2, col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueKey) AS RowNum 
  FROM YourTable
) sub
WHERE sub.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

Comment: "you could use...`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))`...to try and preserve the natural order that the records are stored in."  - Well, that's just wrong. [There is no "natural order" - it's a misconception.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: There's [this old article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml) in a website called 4GuysFromRolla about efficient paging in SQL Server 2000. I think it might still work in 2008. Worth giving it a shot.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank-you very much! Over the years I had doubted the validity of that statement, but never got round to confirming for sure. So I have now removed it. Thanks also for the useful links, I will have a look at those :)

Answer (score 9):

If you use MSSQL 2012 try OFFSET-FETCH clause. It is the best solution!

Example: `SELECT … ORDER BY orderid OFFSET 25 ROWS` fetches only the next 25 rows.

It means this query will return from 25 to 50 records. The `ORDER BY` clause is mandatory, so if you don't want to use order, use `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`

Comment: The question tags would suggest they are using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Yes best solution you had proposed, provided we are on MS SQL 2012. But we are on MS SQL 2008 & on 2008 R2.. Thanks for your time..