# Inserting bulk data into MySQL using node JavaScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to fetch data from SQL server and insert into MySQL. I have fetching around 1 lac's record. Fetching of record is done correctly but during insertion of records into MySQL it will not insert data at once. I need to refresh MySQL to see new records.

```
var sql       = require('mssql');
var mysql     = require("mysql");

var config = {
    user     : 'sa', 
    password : '******',
    server   : 'serverurl', 
    database : 'DB',
    stream   : true //work with large amount of rows
};

var connection1 = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'test'
});

connection1.connect();

var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {

    if(err)
        console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    // request.stream = true; // You can set streaming differently for each request 

    request.query('select TOP 100000 * FROM ShipmentAuditLog WITH (NOLOCK)'); // or request.execute(procedure); 


    request.on('recordset',function(col){
        console.time('Time-Taken');
    });

    // Emitted for each row 
    request.on('row', function(row) {

        syncing(row);
        // console.log('Row Inserted');

    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    // Emitted for the last one
    request.on('done', function(returnValue) {
        console.timeEnd('Time-Taken');
        connection.close();
    });
});

var syncing = function(row){
    connection1.query('INSERT INTO shipmentauditlog SET ?', row, function(err,res) {

        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        // else
            // console.log('Added');

     });
 };
```

Comment: You might need to do a commit, isn't that a relational database thing? I haven't done it in a while, but I think I had something similar in the past.

Comment: @Ewald :- data is stored in mysql but the problem is, it's not storing data at once

Comment: Now I am confused, the data is in MySQL, but it's not there immediately, which could be that it's happening faster than the MySQL commit to disk frequency, so it's still in logs, being processed? Is that the problem?

Comment: @Ewald yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to recreate the same effect when trying to insert thousands of fake records into a MySQL database as well. This obviously overloads the logs (because of ACID compliance) so you have two choices - either relax the ACID compliance for the duration of the insert (see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/is-it-safe-to-use-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-2)) although that's a VERY BAD IDEA usually, or, the better solution, is to use NodeJS to insert your records in batches instead of one by one.

What I suggest is that you read, depending on how big the records are, 20 or 30 of them at a time, and build a multi-insert to add the data to MySQL. See [this link for the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

So you'd end up doing something like this instead:

```
'INSERT INTO shipmentauditlog VALUES (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,1,1), (1,1,3);'
```

The other alternative, if this is a massive, once-of operation, is to use NodeJS to read all the records out and create a TXT document with all the data. MySQL has very good support for bulk loading of massive amounts of data. This would be a lot faster since MySQL would be reading the data from the file in batches and inserting it as it goes along. That would be my preferred option if I had to load significant amounts of data. Please see the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for full details.

A simple example would be:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.txt' INTO TABLE shipmentauditlog 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: i'll try your soluntions. Please tell me one more thing how can I bulk insert array of objects using node-mysql. I search for this but found only bulk insert using array of array i.e. 2D array... do u Have any idea???

Comment: Since MySQL is not an object database, I don't see how you can insert an array of objects. You will have to serialize them to a string, but then you lose all the relational database advantages. If you really need to persist objects, are you sure MySQL is the database you need?

Comment: :- sorry dude... I told you wrong thing. its not object it's json object which I want to store in mysql table

Comment: Ah that's great news - you can store a JSON object as a string - just stringify it as you write it, then you can read it and recreate the JSON object directly from it again, no sweat!

Comment: :- I have successfully implemented your solution (Bulk insert into mysql) it will take 0.4 sec to insert records into DB which is fine but my node takes around 10 -12 sec to fetch 1 lac records from SQL server. I have to improve node js speed. (need 4-5 sec to fetch record)

Comment: Are you still setting one record at a time in Node?  If you want to increase the speed, you will have to insert in batches, let's say, of 10 records at a time in a single insert statement. That's the best way I can think of to speed things up if you don't want to use bulk insert files.

Comment: I am using bulk insert as per you suggest ('INSERT INTO shipmentauditlog VALUES (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,1,1), (1,1,3).......;') which is working fine but my problem is with node js fetching records from sql server which takes more time

Comment: Ah, I see!  You are selecting a LOT of records at a time, that will definitely slow things down. How about selecting from SQL Server in smaller batches?  See for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494393/what-is-the-best-way-to-fetch-records-batch-wise-from-sql-server some help there. I haven't done this in ages, but a smaller batch from SQL Server will probably result in faster results.

Comment: I want my node application get max 5 sec to read 1 lac records. do not understand what to do. Node still get 10 + sec. I stuck from last 2 days. Help me guyz

Comment: Depending on how large your records are, you might simply have a problem with bandwidth and latency during the read operation.  The way your current operation works is that the records are read and then inserted into the MySQL database, so your write time is part of your read time. The only way to make the read faster, is to not write the data until you've read everything, removing the delay, but you will use a tremendous amount of memory for 100k records.

Comment: my machine' s configuration is RAM 4 GB , Intel Pentium (R) CPU G2030 @3.00 GHz... is that the reason for my node application performance????

Comment: Node is single-threaded, all of what you are doing is happening in a single thread, so the reading has to complete before the writing can start. The design of the application is slow, I think that's where the problem comes in.